# RBS Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-database, rbs

I Enabled RBS on our SharePoint farm using the tech net article (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631(v=office.15).aspx) and i was able to successfully test the RBS for one content Database but whenever i am trying to enable RBS in another Content DB i am getting the below error ,I was using the same power shell script that was used in the technet article and still not able to enable RBS in any other content DB.

Can you please suggest where might be the error?
Also i am attaching the screenshot of the error.I did do an server restart after enabling RBS in the Farm

[image: First Content DB "RBS Configured Succesfully]

[image: Second Content DB]

Comment: did you provision the blob store for the 2nd content db? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631(v=office.15).aspx#provision

Comment: Yes Waqas the DBAs enabled it in all content Dbs

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? How to install RBS on additional databases?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have RBS installed for the second database, as indicated by `$rbss.Installed()` returning false. You must first install RBS for this database before you can enable it. Now this one is a bit tricky - MSDN documentation for some reason doesn't actually list all the steps required to properly install it, at least for SP2010. However, [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pramodbalusu/archive/2011/07/09/rbs-and-sharepoint-2010.aspx) blog does - it's for SP2010, but some information may be relevant. See "Enable RBS on another content database" section. The part missing from MSDN is that you must execute this command instead of the one used for the first database:

```
msiexec /qn /i rbs.msi REMOTEBLOBENABLE=1 FILESTREAMPROVIDERENABLE=1 DBNAME=”WSS_Content_NEW” FILESTREAMSTORENAME=FilestreamProvider_1 ADDLOCAL=EnableRBS,FilestreamRunScript DBINSTANCE=”DBInstanceName”
```

Without this, your RBS tables won't get created properly. However, note that the author of the blog says "there are issues of RBS installation with SQL server 2012 and SharePoint 2013 following this blog", so other than the above command I'd still otherwise follow MSDN steps, and only use this if nothing else works.

Comment: I finally got to try this `msiexec` and while it works in SharePoint 2010/SQL Server 2008, it doesn't work for SharePoint 2013/SQL Server 2012, nor do any of the instructions on the MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

For the second, or more content databases, again run the SQL script, changing the values of ContentDbName where present to reflect the Content Database.

Instead of the original msiexec command, run the following msiexec command on subsequent databases:

```
1
msiexec /qn /lvx* rbs_install_log_ContentDbName.txt /i RBS.msi REMOTEBLOBENABLE=1 FILESTREAMPROVIDERENABLE=1 DBNAME=ContentDbName ADDLOCAL="EnableRBS,FilestreamRunScript" DBINSTANCE=SQLSERVERNAME
```

On the secondary WFE, run:

```
1
msiexec /qn /lvx* rbs_install_log_ContentDbName.log /i RBS.msi DBNAME=ContentDbName DBINSTANCE=SQLSERVERNAME ADDLOCAL="EnableRBS,FilestreamRunScript"
```

After the script runs successfully, run the PowerShell script against the second content database. Again, uploading a file should work, as should $rbs.Migrate() if you choose to do that.

http://thesharepointfarm.com/2011/03/enabling-rbs-on-multiple-content-databases/